# How to add a cookie banner in Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, cookies

I want to add a cookie banner in the Bootstrap 5 Grayscale template. I found the following cookie banner on Github and it should be rather straight forward to use:
https://github.com/kolappannathan/bootstrap-cookie-banner

I added one part in the header to load the .css and .js file, and at the end of the body the banner code. Nothing is happening when loading the html file. Any ideas what I made wrong?

```
    <!-- Cookie Banner -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./cookie/cookie-banner.css">
    <script async src="./cookie/cookie-banner.js"></script>

</head>



    <!-- Cookie Banner -->
    <div id="cb-cookie-banner" class="alert alert-dark text-center mb-0" role="alert">
        &#x1F36A; This website uses cookies to ensure you get the best experience on our website.
        <a href="https://www.cookiesandyou.com/" target="blank">Learn more</a>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm ms-3" onclick="window.cb_hideCookieBanner()">
        I Got It
        </button>
    </div>
    <!-- End of Cookie Banner -->

</body>
```

The cookie banner to pop-up when loading the index.html.